# How To Make A Method Return A Non-Zero Value Where Expected

Tags: java, android

So I am currently working on an android project and I got stuck at some point; here is the code:

```
public class Readiness {
private Double examAverageReadiness;
private Integer courseReadiness;
private Integer courseScore;
public Integer courseCount;

//Set the number of courses offered
private void setCourseCount(Integer c) {
    courseCount = c;
}

//Get readiness for individual course examinations
//'a' and 'b' are the course test scores
public Integer getCourseReadiness(Integer a, Integer b) {
    Integer c = (a/15) * 100;
    Integer d = (b/15) * 100;
    Integer e = (c+d)/2;
    //Double f = Double.parseDouble(e.toString());
    courseReadiness = e;
    return e;
}
//Get a predicted score in a course examination
public Integer getPredictableCourseScore(Integer a, Integer b) {
    Integer r = (courseReadiness/100) * 70;
    Integer i = r.intValue();
    Integer d = i + a + b;
    courseScore = d;
    return d;
}

//This is the total readiness for a semester examination
public Double examRValue(Double tmc121, Double eds121, Double gst121, Double     
                         gst122, Double cst121) 
{
  Double v = ((tmc121+eds121+gst121+gst122+cst121)/(courseCount*100)) * 100;
  examAverageReadiness = v;
  return v;
}
}
```

I then used it here:

```
    private View.OnClickListener onClicke=new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View v){
        EditText edtTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtTxt);
        edtTxt.setText("hello there!");
        Readiness r = new Readiness();
        r.courseCount = 5;

        //TMC 121
        EditText one = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.v1);
        EditText two = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.v2);
        Integer one1 = Integer.parseInt(one.getText().toString());
        Integer two2 = Integer.parseInt(two.getText().toString());
        Integer p = r.getCourseReadiness(one1, two2);
        Log.d("pdsk", p.toString());
        Integer f = r.getPredictableCourseScore(one1, two2);
        TextView tmc = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tmc121);
        tmc.setText("Readiness: " + p.toString() + "%  ExamScore: " + f);


        //EDS 121
        EditText three = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.v3);
        EditText four = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.v4);
        Integer three3 = Integer.parseInt(three.getText().toString());
        Integer four4 = Integer.parseInt(four.getText().toString());
        Integer e = r.getCourseReadiness(three3, four4);
        Integer s = r.getPredictableCourseScore(three3, four4);
        TextView eds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.eds121);
        eds.setText("Readiness: " + e.toString() + "%  ExamScore: " + s);
      }         
    }
```

This was okay to me until I debugged it and found out that the Readiness.java class's method -

***"getCourseReadiness(integer a, integer b)"***

always returned a 0 (zero) value. This is kinda annoying you know (to me though...) because I expect a non-zero value if I place a non-zero value in the EditText field. So please I hope I can get answers from this platform... (Thanks).

Comment: You didn't say what values of a and b you were using.  But I'm guessing the zeroes are coming from the various integer division operations you're doing in that routine.

Comment: Sorry for that; I'm assuming that "a" is 13 and "b" is 9. Hope this helps...

Comment: Ditto that!  If (a<15 && b<15), then you're going to get zero back.  `14/15 == 0` in integer math.  Use double instead of int, or compute (a*100)/15 instead of (a/15)*100

Comment: P.S.:  Why all the `Integer` objects?  Why not use primitive values?

Comment: Thanks guys, I changed some of the integer methods to double and it worked! But please do you know how I can round up a double value to two decimal places? <thanks>